# WinSCP: copy changes to multiple servers

Tags: ftp, winscp

I wish to FTP my site to multiple servers, I have these servers available in seperate sessions in winSCP. Can I duplicate the changes I make on one to the others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WinSCP supports scripting. You can make a script that uploads (or even better synchronizes) the site. The script can take a parameter with a name of a stored session (site) in WinSCP (or better a [session URL](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/session_url)).

The WinSCP script (`script.txt`) might be like:

```
open %1%
synchronize remote C:\path_to_website /home/website
exit
```

Wrap that to a batch file (`sync_site.bat`) like:

```
winscp.com /script=script.txt /parameter %1
```

And then you can call that for any number of sites (stored sessions) like:

```
call sync_site.bat site1
call sync_site.bat site2
call sync_site.bat site3
```

Some references:
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#syntax

Answer (score 1):

If you are on windows servers you can just use DropBox to mirror the sites from server to server.  You may need to install AlwaysUp or fingure out a different way to run Dropbox as a service.

Some ftp clients support scripting.  Dont know about WinSCP.  With scripting you could essentially write vbs scripts to automate your FTP process and run the updates to multiple hosts.

If you are on windows servers IIS you can also use the WebFarm framework (Free) to have IIS automatically copy content from a master node to all your supscribed nodes.   On linux you can do the same by running a shell script that manually checks the "master node" for the changes and updates the clients by downloading all the sites in the directly.  This can be done via SSH or SFTP, or a bunch of different setups.

Depending on your setup this may be a good question for ServerFault.com

Comment: Drop box is out of the question due to security. I like your answer, but im going to wait and see if anyone has anything slightly more "ready to go"

Comment: Dropbox is secure.  and can use proxies if you want to alter its ports.  If you are on a Mac, Panic Transmit has functionality to accomplish your deployments.  You can also take a look at Good Sync. http://www.goodsync.com/how-it-works/sync-applications/how-to-sync-via-ftp?affid=22e01&gclid=CNTmm_H67rMCFeGDQgodORAAgg